# Select Max Price from different measurement

Tags: sql, sql-server, select

I have record as below

```
Code    Name    Customer Price  Measure Type   Retail Price  Measure Type
D035    ALU    8.00             F              8.00          F  
D035    ALU    9.00             F              NULL          NULL
```

I wish to select the Max price from above record, how I can do that?  The expected record

```
Code    Name    Customer Price  Measure Type   Retail Price  Measure Type
D035    ALU    9.00             F              8.00          F
```

I try select the Max price without group by the measure type and join the selected result with group by measure type but it seems not as expected.

Comment: Tag your question with the database you are using.

Answer (score 1):

The ANSI SQL method would be `order by` and `fetch first 1 row only`:

```
select t.*
from t
order by t.retail_price desc nulls last
fetch first 1 row only;
```

Not all databases support these constructs, but you can generally do something similar.

Answer (score 1):

I Would Like To Say. Your Retail Price Is Decimal Value And then NULL. NULL Insertion is not possible in Decimal Or Numeric Datatype. So I am Assuming, you have a varchar datatype of it.

Also U have used two Column With Same Name [Measure Type]. I have Changed Name Little for Better understanding.

```
Select * 
From [YourTableName]
GROUP By [Code]
,[Name],[Customer Price], [Measure Type], [Retail Price], [Measrue Type] 
HAVING MAX([Customer Price])=(Select TOP 1 MAX([Customer Price]) From [YourTableName])
```

As You dont have any primary key. So, We cant go with JOIN. Thus, this is solution of your Question.